# Jquery object with comma in between

Tags: jquery

I am learning Jquery. I have found a code pattern which I don't understand like this:

```
var o = $(".a.b", c);
o.each(function(){...};
```

.a.b is pointing to `class = a b`, while c is `id = c`

I have searched through the internet but I cannot find similar pattern.
I want to know what this pattern mean and why c is not leaded by #. Thanks.

Comment: It is the context - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: Now the look up for elements with classes `a` and `b` will be restricted to the elements passed as context

Comment: _"want to know what this pattern mean and why c is not leaded by #."_ `"#c"` could be substituted for `c` at `var o = $(".a.b", "#c");` should return same results as `var o = $(".a.b", c);`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It seems that I missed the most basic thing.